# Code Sharing between Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 / Windows 8 (Windows Store)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have a Silverlight 4 class library written in C# that I use as common code for my Windows Phone 7 projects.

What I want is to use this (basic, platform-independent) code in my Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Apps too.

Is there any way?

It's not strong-necessary that the common code has to be stored in a Silverlight 4 (v5 seems not supported by WP7) project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the common code up as a "portable class library" project, targeting the platforms you want (Silverlight and Windows Store in this case). This gives you access to the intersection of those frameworks. This can then be referenced and used by the framework-specific shell projects.

Comment: Rearranging everything can be a real pain in the ass going this way, but it's well worth it later on. I wish that for my earlier apps, I had been more careful keeping things separate, would have made this process *a lot* easier for me.